# Pull information from webpage using wget and Perl Script

Tags: perl, wget

The purpose of this Perl script is to pull information from webpage using wget and Perl. In this case, this is the website I am trying to extract information from: https://nocable.org/tv-listings/bm95-pomona-ca-91768

I only want the title to display. For example,

```
2.1 - The Ellen Degeneress Show
4.1 - NBC News
7.1 - Hell's Kitchen
```

And that's it.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right or wrong. Can anyone help or give some kind of advice on what to do to display just channel 2.1, 4.1 and 7.1 with the title only? Specifically with wget and Perl script. Any response is appreciated it, as I am still learning about Perl.

---

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;

use open qw(:encoding(UTF-8) :std);

my $url = ' https://nocable.org/tv-listings/bm95-pomona-ca-91768';
my $page = get($url) or die "Can't load $url: $!";

my $tec = HTML::TableExtract->new();
$tec->parse($page);

foreach my $rowref ($tec->rows) 
{
    next if not @$rowref;

    # Clean up undefined/whitespace/newlines, often found in HTML
    my @row = map { 
        $_ = '' if not defined;  # keep undefined fields for formatting
        s/^\s*|\s*$//g;          #/ leading and trailing whitespace
        s/\s+|\n/ /g;            # multiple spaces, newlines
        $_                       # return it
    } @$rowref;

    say join ' | ', @row;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your major problem seems to be that you're looking at the wrong table. There are multiple tables on that page and you can use the `attribs` parameter when creating your parser object in order to return the one you're interested in.

```
my $tec = HTML::TableExtract->new(attribs => {id => 'programming_data' });
```

Having added that, your code will print the info for all the channels. Then you need to create a way to identify the channels you're interested in. I used a regex:

```
my @channels = qw(2.1 4.1 7.1);
my $channel_re = '\b(' . join('|', map { quotemeta } @channels) . ')\b';
```

And in the main loop, you can skip channels that you aren't interested in:

```
next unless $rowref->[0] =~ /$channel_re/;
```